# Output of pandas is not as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is snap of my code while practicing pandas, I generated my own data as shown in the snap. The output of this code is not as expected.The third & fourth row datas are not printing with the correct column. Please help with this.
[image: Code Snapshot]

Comment: Sets are unordered (see the dupe). Use lists instead.